# Two answers per day get downvoted – will the system notice this?

Tags: discussion, support

So I have noticed that two of my answers get downvoted each day.

I have seen other posts that mention the system notices serial downvoting, but will the system notice two a day across several days?
I know that the system will revoke downvotes of say ten in a row as that is easily spotted but will it pick up insidious downvoting that is slow?

If the system will not, then how do I proceed? Getting an answer that it won’t be spotted and can’t be changed will suggest the system needs changing.

Comment: In your case, to meaningfully change your reputation, a user would need quite a lot of sock pupets.

Comment: It is not even clear that the system will revoke ten downvotes. There is more to it than sheer numbers. -- In any case, could it possibly be related to your answers?

Comment: @user151413 yes! Especially when some of the highest voted answers get downvoted, which is why I noticed...

Comment: @SolarMike I think you take these things far too personal!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can only see it happened once, [yesterday](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/72855/solar-mike?tab=reputation), but given the close proximity this does look like targeted voting. The script runs in the early UTC hours so it's safe to assume it didn't detect this.

As mentioned in the FAQ [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/295232), you can flag one of the affected posts for ♦ moderator attention, but with only two votes there's nothing much for them to see either (source: I'm a moderator on three other sites in the network). I'd recommend doing that if the pattern continues (and is not reversed automatically).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will see what happens and do what you advise. Cheers.

Comment: Mind that it is more than a single downvoting event, but not all of this is visible to non-moderators since some of the posts in question were deleted since then.

Comment: Ah, good catch.

Answer (score 5):

The system will not automatically reverse this kind of downvoting, but it will eventually still show up and you can flag one of your posts for moderator attention and we can then investigate this.

I your particular case, there are indeed some hints of somebody systematically downvoting you. I will investigate these and address them as appropriate. Since this may involve Stack Exchange staff (as only they can see and undo individual votes), this may take a while.

Comment: Thank you for looking and acting on this, much appreciated.